# htaccess rewrite mod: vanity url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I've looked on SO but wasn't able to find the answer to my issue.

How can I go **from** :

```
 localhost/profile.php?id=22
```

**to:**

```
 localhost/charlie
```

Charlie would be the username (not the first name) here.

I also want to **make sure that whether a user types in**

```
 localhost/profile.php?id=22
```

**or**

```
 localhost/charlie
```

they get redirected to the appropriate profile they're looking for.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+profile\.php\?id=22\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /charlie? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^charlie/?$ /profile.php?id=22 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, going to check this out and will let you know

Comment: Thanks, it does work ! BUT i'm looking for a general script that will work for every user : the id will not always be 22 and the username not Charlie. How should I edit your code?

Comment: But mod_rewrite rules cannot query your database and translate id=22 to Charlie. You better do this redirection in PHP code after getting user name from database for the `$_GET["id"]`